# TCP Socket tunnel or relay

Tags: sockets, terminal, tcp, pipe, tunnel

I am working with some old pieces of laboratory analyzers(sorry I am not allowed to disclose the specific model of the hardware) that communicate with each other with ASTM protocol and I am able to interface with the hardware via telnet.

Got a problem that the analyzer can only act as a TCP Socket server and if I want to link up both of the analyzers I theroitcally have to put a PC in between to tunnel the socket traffic
i.e.
Analyer A, 192.168.0.1, TCP server (port 22)<- PC, 192.168.0.2, TCP client ->Analyer B, 192.168.0.3, TCP server (port 22)

On the PC side the data received from 192.168.0.1:22 is relayed to 192.168.0.3:22 and vice versa.

are there any apps or commands in Linux or Windows that can pipe the data to another IP?

Comment: You should be able to use two instances of `ncat` (or `nc`) with a pipe between them. Look into the `man` page... you might end up with something like: `nc  192.168.0.1 22 0<2way | nc 192.168.0.3 22 1>2way`... but somehow I really doubt that I understood the issue correctly or that this will work.

Comment: This question is more likely to get an answer on ServerFault.com.  Doesn't belong in this forum.